# Set timeout for async function

Tags: javascript, html

I have an async function which fetches Jenkins job names from a remote Jenkins installation, and puts them into a set which then will be displayed in the HTML page.
I need to invoke this async function every n seconds, and refresh the page so that the new results are visible in the HTML page.
I am stuck on setting the timeout for the async function:

```
async function fetchBranches() {
  this.BRANCH_NAMES = new Set();

  await fetch(URL).then(async data => {
    const jobs = data.jobs;
    for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
      const currentJobName = jobs[i].name;  
      await fetch(currentJobName).then(branchData => {
        if(branchData != null){
          const branches = branchData.jobs;
          for (var i = 0; i < branches.length; i++) {
            const branchName = decodeURIComponent(branches[i].name);
            this.BRANCH_NAMES.add(branchName);
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I am trying to set the timeout for the async function with the following:

```
const awaitTimeout = delay =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

const jenkinsTimeout = async () => {
  await fetchBranches();
  console.log(`this.BRANCH_NAMES is ${Array.from(this.BRANCH_NAMES).length} long`);
  await awaitTimeout(5000);
};

jenkinsTimeout()
```

I have 2 problems:

1. This is only invoked once (when I load the page), not every 5 seconds as I would expect.
2. Although the console shows that the set is not empty (so the function did its job), I can't see the results in the HTML page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want `jenkinsTimeout` to be called again, then you need to call it after you've waited for the timeout.

Comment: "*This invoked only once*" `setTimeout` only executes once. You have no code to run it more than once. An alternative would be `setInterval`. "*i cant see the results in the HTML page.*" you never do anything with the results. Just add them to a set and that's it. It's unclear what you expect to update the DOM. And if there *is* something that would update the page - it's not clear how it's supposed to work or why it doesn't here.

Comment: This is as simple as adding `await jenkinsTimeout();` after `await awaitTimeout(5000);`. However, this can be solved without recursion as well.

Comment: Btw: why are you doing `await fetch(URL).then(` kind of coding? `await` was literally introduced to avoid using `.then`.

Comment: More than a week has passed; I guess you lost interest in this question?